# I want an element to be outside of the container in rails application

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

In my rails app I am using Bootstrap and want the image carousel on the home page to be outside of the container so it spans the entire width of the browser. However, in my application.html.erb I have each view being rendered in the container class. What would be the best way to have the image carousel on the home page to be outside of the container?

application.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <%= render 'layouts/bootstrap_flash' %>
  <%= yield %>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
  </footer>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

homepage.html.erb

```
<% if @images.present? %>
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <% @images.each do |image| %>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="<%= image.placement %>" class=<%= 'active' if image.placement == 1 %>></li>
        <% end %>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% @images.each do |image| %>
        <% if image.placement == 1 %>
            <div class="item active">
        <% else %>
            <div class="item">
        <% end %>
            <% if image.destination.present? %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(image.picture(:original), image.destination) %>
          <% else %>
            <%= image_tag(image.picture(:original)) %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the current `.container` div and reopen after the carousel.

homepage.html.erb

```
<% if @images.present? %>
</div><!-- .container -->
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  [...]
</div>
<div class="container">
<% end %>
```